# Delete database shard mapping and shard databases in SQL Server to clean up tenant resources

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure-elasticpool, azure-elastic-sharding

We have a database for each tenant as shown in the screenshot below.
I am trying to delete the tenant DB and clean up and reclaim the resources of a tenant I have anciently created. I tried the following code, however, even though this method executes successfully, no changes take place in the database. The tenant database still remains and mappings are still there in [ShardsGlobal] table.

[image]

What is the proper way to fully delete tenant-specific databases and references from SQL Server?

Please note that we will be using Azure Elastic Pool in production.

```
string shardMapManagerConnectionString = configuration.GetShardMapMangerConnectionString();

ShardMapManager shardMapManager;
shardMapManager = ShardMapManagerFactory.GetSqlShardMapManager(
                shardMapManagerConnectionString,
                ShardMapManagerLoadPolicy.Lazy);

var shardMap = shardMapManager.GetListShardMap<T>(configuration.ShardMapName);

if (shardMap.TryGetMappingForKey(key, out PointMapping<T> mapping))
{
    if (mapping.Status == MappingStatus.Online)
    {
        // `mapping =` on next line is needed
        mapping = shardMap.MarkMappingOffline(mapping);
    }

    shardMap.DeleteMapping(mapping);

    var shard = shardMap.GetShard(mapping.Shard.Location);
    shardMap.DeleteShard(shard);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-scale-shard-map-management?view=azuresql#modifying-a-shard-map) for DeleteShard you'll notice this part:

> These methods do not have any impact on the databases themselves, only on metadata in the shard map.

Have you tried the approach presented in the [Azure Samples](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/sql-database-dotnet-manage-sql-dbs-in-elastic-pool/blob/master/Program.cs)?

To delete both shard and DB, I would assume, based on the [FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-scale-faq?view=azuresql#does-the-split-merge-tool-provision--or-delete--a-database-during-a-split-or-merge-operation), you'd have to delete the shard first, then the DB.

Comment: thanks, what is the precise algorithm to clean up everything, that is shard map and the db resources?
If I delete the db would that clean up the shard map?